# Regex with NOT option match c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text input-

```
Host             Expiration  Features            
**172.17.64.120    never**       CPSM-C-BASE CPSB-NPM CPSB-EPM CPSB-LOGS CPSB-MNTR CPSB-MPTL CPSB-UDIR CPSB-PRVS CPSB-GBLP CK-77B458DF8D52
**172.17.64.120    never**       CPSM-C-U CPSB-NPM CPSB-EPM CPSB-LOGS CPSB-MNTR CPSB-MPTL CPSB-UDIR CPSB-PRVS CPSB-GBLP CK-FF18475CE402
**10.10.5.17       10May2018**   CPSM-C-U CPSB-NPM CPSB-EPM CPSB-LOGS CPSB-MNTR 

(some other text..)

LICENSE **10.10.5.17 10May2018** 
LICENSE **172.17.64.120 never** 
LICENSE **172.17.64.120 never**
```

I want to get all the 3 licenses without duplication - 
The following regex pattern - 
`\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s*(\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}`|never)
matches these results:

```
172.17.64.120    never
172.17.64.120    never
10.10.5.17       10May2018
10.10.5.17 10May2018
172.17.64.120 never
172.17.64.120 never
```

The issue is, that I want to get the results without duplications.
Is there anyway to insert additional not option to the regex that will not match the last 3 result ***(those who start with LICENSE+spaces)***

```
10.10.5.17 10May2018
172.17.64.120 never
172.17.64.120 never
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you filter returning matches array later?

Comment: wouldnt you just want to add [^LICENSE \*\*] at the front of your regex

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are saying... If your regex is working, then don't complicated it, just use a `Distinct` on the results

```
List<string> results = <put your matches in here>;

results = results.Distinct();
```

[Enumerable.Distinct Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns distinct elements from a sequence by using the default
>   equality comparer to compare values.

Answer (score 0):

You may prepend your pattern with a word boundary and a negative lookbehind that will fail the matches after `LICENSE` + one or more whitespaces:

```
\b(?<!\bLICENSE\s+)(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s*(\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}|never)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3C!%5CbLICENSE%5Cs%2B%29%28%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%7B3%7D%29%5Cs*%28%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B4%7D%7Cnever%29%5Cb&i=Host%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Expiration%20%20Features%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A172.17.64.120%20%20%20%20never%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CPSM-C-BASE%20CPSB-NPM%20CPSB-EPM%20CPSB-LOGS%20CPSB-MNTR%20CPSB-MPTL%20CPSB-UDIR%20CPSB-PRVS%20CPSB-GBLP%20CK-77B458DF8D52%0D%0A172.17.64.120%20%20%20%20never%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CPSM-C-U%20CPSB-NPM%20CPSB-EPM%20CPSB-LOGS%20CPSB-MNTR%20CPSB-MPTL%20CPSB-UDIR%20CPSB-PRVS%20CPSB-GBLP%20CK-FF18475CE402%0D%0A10.10.5.17%20%20%20%20%20%20%2010May2018%20%20%20CPSM-C-U%20CPSB-NPM%20CPSB-EPM%20CPSB-LOGS%20CPSB-MNTR%0D%0A%0D%0ALICENSE%2010.10.5.17%2010May2018%20%0D%0ALICENSE%20172.17.64.120%20never%20%0D%0ALICENSE%20172.17.64.120%20never%20).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\bLICENSE\s+)` - immediately to the left of the current location, there can't be `LICENSE` followed with 1+ whitespace chars
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})` - Group 1: one, two or three digits, and then 3 occurrences of a dot followed with 1 to 3 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{4}|never)` - 1 or 2 digits, 3 ASCII letters and 4 digits, or a whole word `never`
- `\b` - word boundary.